# OpenFlow - Sending Port statistics as an Action

Tags: sdn, openflow, openvswitch

OpenFlow allows a controller to request port statistics from the a switch using a message, and the controller in return receives a reply with the statistics.

For example, in Ryu we can use `ryu.ofproto.ofproto_v1_3_parser.OFPPortStatsRequest` for this purpose.

Is there a way to get the port statistics from a switch without issuing a request message from the controller, but possibly as an action by the switch on receipt of a particular type of packet?

Comment: As far as I know (my knowledge covers only OpenFlow until v1.3), this is not possible, what you are trying to achieve. The switch itself isn't able to send statistics without a request, sent by controller. In my case, I had to consequently observe those statistics, the only which worked fine, was to periodically request statistics from the switches.

Comment: Hello, I have added an action to the ovs code that sends port statistics of the ingress port of any flow. Couldn't find such a feature in any of the openflow standards.